# Dot product of basis vectors and dual basis vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors

I'm currently reading a text on tensor algebra, and at this point (fairly early on I might add), they're discussing dual basis vectors. The author mentions that one of the defining properties of dual basis vectors are that the dot product between a dual basis vector and the original basis vector (i.e. the vector with the same index) must be 1.

I'm just having a little bit of trouble understanding why this is the case. From an intuitive standpoint I can sort of understand this, as that dual vector must "correspond" to the original basis vector, but regardless it's been a bit of a mental roadblock for me. Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks a ton!

Comment: The dual basis vectors are the transpose of the basis vectors. In other words, for each of the column vectors corresponding to a basis vector, the corresponding dual vector is the same vector as a row vector.

Answer (score 1):

It’s true by definition. As to why the dual basis is defined that way, it’s because it uniquely determines each dual basis vector.